Issue with Dialogflow and Cloud Function Integration: No Response in Test Agent UI
I'm facing an issue where my Dialogflow CX agent's webhook, implemented as a Google Cloud Function, appears to receive requests successfully but does not return any response in the Dialogflow test agent UI. Despite the Cloud Function logging a successful HTTP 200 response, the UI remains empty.I have set up a Dialogflow CX agent with intents that trigger webhook calls to a Google Cloud Function. The function processes the request, queries BigQuery based on provided date parameters, and generates a response. However, this response is not displayed in the Dialogflow test agent UI after the webhook call.
Below is the relevant part of my Cloud Function (qlik_app_chatbot) and the associated request logs from Cloud Function:
# Cloud Function Implementation
@functions_framework.http
def qlik_app_chatbot(request):
    # Code for setting up credentials, initializing BigQuery client, and handling request
    try:
        req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
        if not req:
            raise ValueError("Invalid JSON format or empty request body.")
        
        intent = req.get("fulfillmentInfo", {}).get("tag")
        parameters = req.get("fulfillmentInfo", {}).get("parameters")
        if not (intent and parameters):
            raise ValueError("Missing 'intent' or 'parameters' in request.")
        
        # Parse date parameters
        start_date_obj = parameters.get('start_date')
        end_date_obj = parameters.get('end_date')
        if not (start_date_obj and end_date_obj):
            raise ValueError("Missing 'start_date' or 'end_date' in parameters.")
        
        start_date = parse_date(start_date_obj)
        end_date = parse_date(end_date_obj)
        
        # Determine intent and fetch appropriate response
        if intent == 'TotalConfirmedCases':
            response_text = fetch_total_confirmed_cases(client, start_date, end_date)
        elif intent == 'TotalDeaths':
            response_text = fetch_total_deaths(client, start_date, end_date)
        # Add other intent handling logic here...

        return jsonify({'fulfillmentText': response_text})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'fulfillmentText': 'An error occurred while processing your request.'}), 500

# Parsing function for date objects
def parse_date(date_obj):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(date_obj, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect date format; should be YYYY-MM-DD")

# Example logs from Cloud Function
2024-07-08 10:09:19.418 BST
Function execution started 
2024-07-08 10:09:20.540 BST
Request received: {'fulfillmentInfo': {'tag': 'TotalConfirmedCases', 'parameters': {'start_date': '2021-12-01', 'end_date': '2022-12-31'}}, ...}
2024-07-08 10:09:20.544 BST
Response sent successfully with status 200

The Cloud Function successfully receives requests and logs the intent along with parsed parameters (start_date and end_date).
It processes the request and constructs a response using BigQuery data.
Despite logging a successful response (HTTP 200), the response doesn't appear in the Dialogflow test agent UI.
How can I ensure that the response generated by my Cloud Function is correctly sent back to the Dialogflow test agent UI?
Are there any specific configurations or checks I should perform to troubleshoot why the response isn't displayed?
Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have set up a Dialogflow CX agent with intents that trigger webhook calls to a Google Cloud Function. The function processes the request, queries BigQuery based on provided date parameters, and generates a response. However, this response is not displayed in the Dialogflow test agent UI after the webhook call.
